# Why does my PostgreSQL View see uncommitted data?

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-kafka, transactions

I have a JDBC sink connector (kafka) which writes data to `table_one` in my PostgreSQL 10 database. On insert or update to `table_one` I have row level trigger which inserts data into `table_two` which looks like:

```
id_field      | transaction_id
PK of Table A | transaction ID for transaction that inserted row in TABLE A
```

The `transaction_id` is set in the trigger using the psql function `txid_current()`. I then have a JDBC source connector which polls a PostgreSQl View which essentially does:

```
SELECT * FROM table_two
```

Lets say I insert 10,000 rows into `table_one`. If I wait for this transaction (and the trigger) to run to completion before polling the view connector I can see that all 10,000 rows are inserted into `table_two` with the same `transaction_id`.

However, if the connector polls the view before the insert into `table_one` (and the trigger) has finished executing I see the view returns a partial result.

I would expect the view to return ALL or NONE - what is going on here?

Comment: This needs clarification. What exactly is that "JDBC source connector"? Which logical decoding plugin are you using? It seems that you are using Kafka both to write to the database and to read from the database, is that right? What are the SQL statements actually executed on `table_two`?

Comment: That's correct, kafka writes to the database, a trigger runs, updates a second table and then kafka reads from a view which joins on table two (select * from view)

Comment: There were more questions than that one. Please [edit] the question and add the information there. Essentially, we have to be able to reproduce what you are seeing to understand what is going on.